# Link address on new line in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, line-breaking, url

I have the following reference in my bibliography.db file:

```
@misc{vespa_url,
    author = "{ESS}",
    howpublished = "\url{https://europeanspallationsource.se/instruments/vespa}",
    title = "Vespa main page at {ESS}",
}
```

This is the result:

[image: i]

Of course my latex editor (gnome-latex) complains about it:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
```

I want latex to automatically write any link in a new line, like:

> ESS,“Vespa main page at ESS.”
>   https://europeanspallationsource.se/instruments/vespa.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If hyperref package is used, the following will add a line break in front of url:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{slashed}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\url@#1{\newline\hyper@linkurl{\Hurl{#1}}{#1}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
  \frontmatter
  \mainmatter
  Hi. \cite{test}

  \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
  \bibliography{db.bib}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The address is indeed on a new line, but the "pdf link" (the light-blue box) is not. Look: https://i.imgur.com/OnpMDim.png

Comment: @JimmyScionti It is in a new line for me. Can you make a test file that shows your problem?

Comment: I try to send you the complete list of packages that I use: https://justpaste.it/6j7zd
I can't make a new file right now.

This is what I get now, by the way: https://i.imgur.com/L8dSA4y.png

Comment: @JimmyScionti Don't sent a list of package, sent a document that reproduces the problem

Comment: Here it is: https://filebin.net/f9ir1hiee982d5v5

Comment: @JimmyScionti Please see the updated answer

Comment: Thank you a lot, @Maeve!